# how to find form closest a button with a specific text value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a web page that has multiple forms. 
I'm trying to locate the form that has a "Add" button inside of it, and then assign an id to the form. 
Then I need to find an element within this named form... an input element, and assign a value to it.

so for example, i have the following test HTML:

```
<H1>Add A Call Route</H1><DL>
<form action="myapp/controller/addcallroute" method="POST">

<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >

<input class=" hidden" type="hidden"  name="rule_id"  value=""  id="rule_id" >


<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

</FORM>
```

Here's the code I am trying to use to find the right form.. and assign an id to it:

```
    var $callroute_form = $(":contains('Add')").closest("form");
    $callroute_form.attr('id',"callroute_form");
```

When I debug in the console and try to see what the value of $("#callroute_form") is, I just get "[]".

ultimately, what I need to do is assign a value to the "rule_id" field.  But I have multiple rule_id fields in multiple forms... 
Alternatively, I guess I good try to look for the "Add" button, and populate the "rule_id" that's closest to it..?

thanks.

Comment: `$(":contains('Add')")` This will scan all tags in your DOM. Highly inefficient filter. Don't use this as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector doesn't fit here because it searches for an element inner text, not value.

Try the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var $callroute_form = $("input[value='Add']").closest("form");
```

---

From the `:contains` documentation:

> **contains selector**
>
> **Description:** Select all elements that contain the specified text.

Answer (score 1):

To find the form by the way you explained and add an id to it:

```
// first method:
$('input[value="Add"]').parent().attr('id',"callroute_form");

// second method:
$('input[value="Add"]').closest('form').attr('id',"callroute_form");
```

To find elements in this form and edit the value:

```
$('#callroute_form').find('input[name"rule_id"]').val('newvalue');
```

Comment: You should use `.closest` like in the OP. Using parent is too coupled with the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Pick all forms and filter the form on the basis of the input button. Now, do whatever you want to do with the form.

```
$('form').filter( function() {
  return $(this).find("input[value='Add']").length == 1;
}).attr('id', 'callroute_form' )';
```